# Wiring Servers to 240VAC single phase 1 wire

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am attempting to wire several servers up to 240v. Some servers have PSU's which are capable of adjusting to 240v from 120v, others are strictly 240v no questions asked.
According to the manufacture's website I need to use 240v single phase or 240v 3 phase, and 3 Phase is not an option where I live.
My question is, living inside the United States with 2 120v Hot Wires in a residential home, how do I combine those to a single 240v hot wire with neutral and ground. It doesn't say whether I can use 2 hot wires to achieve 240 or not, and I don't want to nuke thousands of dollars in equipment. I plan to install a UPS as well which might be an answer to the question.  I can provide specs on the servers and PSU's as needed. Thank you!

Comment: Will probably need a transformer for 120 to 240.  Connecting two hots together from different phases is not nice.  Importing electric/electronic devices made for a different electrical system adds problems.

Comment: 240 to 240 is going to be much easier if a transformer is needed.

Comment: Model #s and other details would help *a lot*.

Comment: I can break down the specs as follows: The server that requires 240VAC is a Dell M1000e blade enclosure, the PSU's are Dell E3000E-S0 (Here is the link to the pictures of the PSU's: (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YCX-Fqp4utgNybu-lQoD2U12IMRuv5CV?usp=sharing) I understand that connecting 2 120 volt cables together do not equal 240v, it equals fireworks. Hence why I am asking the question. Thank you!

Comment: Do these servers have cords with plugs on the ends?  If so, pictures of the plugs might help.

Comment: You could use a 220V to 220V isolation transformer. How much power are we talking. Consider the cost to do the conversion vs replacing the PSU.

Comment: Wolf - be aware those servers draw a lot of electricity, and convert most of it to noise and heat.  They're not really ideal for running in one's home, just saying you might be better served by selling them on ebay and buying some normal desktop systems.   I've been there before.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like some import-stuff if it expects 240 line and neutral.

240V devices here use **both** hots (not "combined") and **no** neutral (from the house supply.) Which would mean wiring one hot to *device-line* and one hot to *device-neutral*, and ground to *device-ground.* Depending on how the thing is built, that's either fine, or not. If it's NRTL-listed for use in this area, it's fine.

Using an isolation transformer (1:1 winding - 240V in from both hots, 240V out isolated so one side can be grounded as a *separately derived source* neutral) would be a way to get 240V line to neutral, if that's needed. that will require a VA or KVA rating as large or larger than your power requirement for the server supplies, and will waste a little power as heat (nothing is 100% efficient)

If the neutral (or Line 2, which is a clue that it's designed for this market) connection on the device has no issues (safety or operational) operating 120V above ground, it can be direct wired to a US-Style hot. Server power supplies intended and listed for the North American market expect that.

Comment: Not sure where Dell made their servers back in the day when this was made but it was designed for the US electrical infrastructure. Also I am not 100% sure whether it expects 240 hot on one leg, neutral on another and ground on the 3rd, I only made this assumption since the PSU works that way with 120VAC, 1 hot, 1 neutral, 1 ground. If this isn't the case, that's great, and easy!

Comment: This is a standard 240V two "hots" + ground connector. In the US, that's 2 hots (resulting in ~ 208V or ~ 240V depending on service). In Europe/Asia that's 1 hot + neutral anywhere from 210V to 240V depending on service. The device does not know or care about neutral.

Comment: @WolfMason As stated in the answer, if it was deisigned for this market (no matter where it was built) and 240V capable, hot-hot-ground is all it needs, no fuss, no muss, and nothing complicated.

Comment: @WolfMason It is a basic misunderstanding of how "hot" vs. "neutral" works. With the exception (big exception - see "3 wire dryer problem") of things that mix up ground with neutral, **no device** knows or cares about "neutral" per se or what the voltage is between hot and ground. All they care about (except for some big motors) is "what is the voltage between my 2 input wires" - for US that's 120 or 240 (or sometimes 208). For Europe that's typically between 220 and 240. Etc. The fact that in one place it is hot & neutral and another it is hot & hot and that in one place ground is 120 to each

Comment: hot and in another it is 120 to one hot and 0 to the other (US neutral), etc. really doesn't affect functionality and power usage. But all of it can affect *safety*. But in the case of a Dell product like this, I'm not worried about the safety.

Comment: If a device is made for the EU market, it is guaranteed to be safe on American hot-to-hot 240V. That's because the "EU universal" ([CEE 7/7](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:CEE_7-7.jpg)) plugs aren't polarized, so the device has absolutely no way of knowing which prong is hot and which one is neutral, thus it can't treat either one specially (both have to have the same insulation wrt ground).

Answer (score 4):

> My question is, living inside the United States with 2 120v Hot Wires in a residential home, how do I combine those to a single 240v hot wire with neutral and ground.

You can't.  You're absolutely not allowed to make suicide cords like that which have two plugs on them and merge independent 120V circuits. Those things can kill you in unexpected ways.  Fate favors little girls, fools, and ships named Enterprise... but electricity doesn't.

You need to have an electrician come in and wire you a proper 240V circuit.  It will have whichever socket you ask for that is designed for 240V, such as the two on the right.  See the family resemblance? Depending on how your existing circuits are laid out, sometimes a 120V circuit can be converted to 240V easily as swapping socket and breaker.

[image]

For 30A they also have these larger sockets.  You don't need neutral (white) if all loads on the PSU are 240V.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring ground (don't *actually* ignore ground, it is critical for safety; but every circuit here needs one ground wire so it doesn't enter into the equation), a 120V circuit or a 240V circuit needs 2 wires, either 14 AWG for 15A or 12 AWG for 20A. If a circuit needs *both* 120V and 240V (e.g., Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC) or a standard clothes dryer or oven) then it uses 3 wires. 120V is hot + neutral. 240V is hot + hot. 120V/240V is hot + hot + neutral.

The good news is, that means you can wire up receptacles for servers using the same type of 2-wire cable as you use for standard 120V circuits. All you have to do special is:

- Mark the white wire with colored tape on both ends to indicate it is a hot wire.
- Connect black and white wires to the two poles of a double-pole breaker.
- Use the appropriate receptacle - NEMA 6-15 for 15A, [6-20 for 20A](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-Commercial-Grade-Double-Pole-Single-Outlet-White-R52-05821-0WS/100356999):

[image: 6-20 receptacle]

But there is a big catch: You usually can't just remark the wires and reuse an existing circuit. That's because in most houses each circuit (a) serves multiple receptacles in multiple rooms (and you can't do this unless you change *all* of those receptacles at the same time, and that would go against the idea of being able to provide lots of *dedicated* power to your servers) and (b) most homes have just barely enough receptacles to meet code requirements. So usually that means running a new circuit (e.g., 12/2 cable from a new breaker to a new receptacle). That is easy in an unfinished basement, much harder (but varies a lot) in a finished room on a different floor.

Based on critical information from comments, this is a Dell E3000E-S0 power supply, rated for 3000W = 240V @ 16A. Total power is proportionally lower if used on 208V or 220V. So this is a perfect match for a 240V 20A circuit @ 80% continuous derate. It is also from a reputable manufacturer that regularly produces equipment designed to be used around the world, so using it on a 240V circuit in the US is perfectly normal. The connector looks like a C19/C20 connector, which is perfectly normal for this type of device.

Comment: Are you sure about *"Total power is proportionally lower if used on 208V or 220V."*? Does it derate the output? Because normal switch mode power supplies have the same maximum output power across their input range, and therefore draw more current at lower voltage (unlike resistive loads)

Comment: @ChrisH I would *guess* the output is derated to avoid exceeding the nominal input current.

Comment: @ChrisH If you look at a picture of this power supply, it actually says "Maximum output power at 220-240V 3000W" and "Maximum output power at 200V-220V 2750W".

Answer (score 2):

Most European appliances require two wires with 230V AC between them (240 is the same thing) and a separate ground for protective purposes.

The usual case is one of the wires to be hot and the other to be neutral, but this is not generally required. The ground is not normally expected to interact with either and its protective role works in all cases (provided adequate protection from the source side).

The US-style split phase or some other arrangements (e.g. half-waves in either direction like in the cheap "modified-sine" inverters) work acceptably well and are even legal.

Where these assumptions go wrong?

Some devices (e.g. some UPS devices) do extensive control of the input power and one of the power quality critera is if the designated neutral to be within few volts from the ground. When fed with split phase they will consider the ground disconnected and complain about the fact (up to and including not using the power source in question).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take the two 120 volt legs and hook them together to get 240 volts. They are different phases and hooking them toether would cause a big spark, fire and tripping breakers and blowing transformer fuses. Speaking of transformers, you could get a 120V to 240V step up transformer to run your servers. The transformers come in a variety of different wattages.

Comment: Transformers would be a waste, even if 100% efficient. The reason to use 240V servers is to get more total power. A 240V 20A circuit would require a 120V 40A circuit (which would require expensive large wire) to run from a transformer.

Comment: Why do you need a transformer when most US houses have a 240V supply already?

Comment: @SimonB  US houses have 240V phase to phase, not phase to neutral.

Comment: @JACK Correct, phase to phase. Which means run a pair of wires on the two phases (hots) and done.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  but the OP's looking for a single 240V line and a neutral for some of his servers. He's not using 240V servers to get more power, he's just trying to get them to work in the US. So for some of them, transformers would work.  Our 120V /20 amp circuit would be equivalent to a 240V/10 amp circuit.

Comment: Actually OP really isn't clear about total power needed or neutral. Reality is that hardly anything that uses two wires (i.e. excluding 120 240 combos like us clothes dryers) cares whether second wire is hot or neutral.

Comment: Yeah, going into this, I wasn't exactly clear as what kind of power requirements were needed, hence my reply above stating what is being used. I can repost it here though: The server that requires 240VAC is a Dell M1000e blade enclosure, the PSU's are Dell E3000E-S0 (Here is the link to the pictures of the PSU's: (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YCX-Fqp4utgNybu-lQoD2U12IMRuv5CV?usp=sharing) I understand that connecting 2 120 volt cables together do not equal 240v, it equals fireworks. Hence why I am asking the question.

Comment: I downvoted this because two 120 volt legs is literally how 240V power works in the USA while this answer makes it seem like it isn't and a transformer is needed.

Comment: @user253751  Please read the answer again.  You cannot take two residential  120V legs and  connect them together to get 240V.  You can connect a load between them  and get 240V.  The transformer is to step up the 120V to neutral circuit to a 240V to neutral (not phase to phase) cirvuit..

Comment: @JACK the OA does not need 240 to neutral, they need to power the particular appliance which is pretty much OK with 240V derived from the split phase setup.

Comment: @fraxinus  Right you are. I was addressing the "others are strictly 240v no questions asked."  I answered this first and a lot has come out in the wash since then. i didn't come back and change anything because i was watching football.